# Can I write protocol behave similar to Encodable & Decodable?

Tags: swift, swift4, swift-protocols, codable

The swift4's `Codable` protocol is extremely useful. It provide default implementation functions if the conformation is rightly defined.

E.g. this is totally fine:

```
struct Good: Codable {
    var foo: String // Non-optional
    var bar: Int?  // Optional
}
```

but this one will raise compile error with the request to create protocol conforming

```
struct Bad: Codable {
   var foo: UIButton // Non-optional raise compile error for not conforming Codable Protocol
   var bar: UIView? // optional is okay (not compile error because when decode failed, it fallback to nil)
   var codable: SomeCodable // if the property is also Codable, then it's fine too!
}
```

So, the question is: Can I write a protocol that can require its conformance to follow itself (like properties need to conform same protocol)?

If yes, how? If no, why?

Also, I'd also like to know how defining `CodingKeys` inside the struct can change the encode/decode behaviour? Can I make something like that in my protocol as well?

Comment: Rules like what? It's unclear what you mean, for instance what is the "rule" for UIButton and UIView?

Comment: *optional is okay*, No, it's not. It's not a question of optional, it's a question of protocol conformance. Views like `UIButton` and `UIView` don't conform to `Codable` per se because it's pointless to encode/decode an abstract view.

Comment: The automatic synthesis of Codable conformance is requires support from the *compiler.* So no, you cannot do something similar yourself (unless you patch the compiler).

Comment: I've updated the question to make it clearer for Joakim and vadian. Thanks Martin, you can write a short answer about the compiler and I'll gladly accept the answer. Also, I'd prefer you can explain something about how `CodingKeys` work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1187415/martin-r) is correct you cannot make this on your own without touching the compiler.

First let's take a look at this basic example where I explain how coding keys are used.

```
struct CodableStruct: Codable {
let primitive: Int // No issues yet

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case primitive
    // This is the default coding key (i.e the JSON has structure ["primitive": 37]
    // You can change this key to anything you need
    //
    // ex case primitive = "any_thing_you_want"
    // JSON has to have structure ["any_thing_you_want": 37]
}
```

}

Changing the codingKey just changes the key the code will use when looking to "decode" that value from your JSON.

Now let's talk about the compiler. Let's say we create another `struct`

```
struct NotCodableStruct {
    let number: Double
}
```

This struct does not conform to Codable. If we go and add this into our previous struct we have:

```
struct CodableStruct: Codable {
    let primative: Int
    let notCodable: NotCodableStruct // doesn't compile because this doesn't conform to codable

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case primative
        case notCodable
    }
}
```

Since `NotCodableStruct` does not conform to `Codable` the compiler complains. In other words all variables in a struct or object that conforms to `Codable` must also conform to `Codable`. See the below screenshot for more information.

[image: compiler error]

Of course if you make `NotCodableStruct` conform to `Codable` everyone will be happy again. Since there is no way for you to enforce the requirement that all variables conform to `Codable` you cannot make a similar protocol.

Comment: While your answer does extend Martin's comment, the information about `CodingKeys` is still not clear on how it's working. Can I have more than one `CodingKeys`? Do it have to be named `CodingKeys` or `WhateverKeys` is fine?

Comment: The name `CodingKeys` is required by the protocol. You cannot have more than one `CodingKeys` each variable gets one and only one key and there is one and only one set of `CodingKeys`